# Disable UISearchBar search icon and placeholder text animation on becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar, placeholder, becomefirstresponder

I have a UISearchBar that I want to display when the user taps a button. In the buttonPress method, I create the searchBar and add it as a subview, then call `[searchBar becomeFirstResponder]`. If I take out this becomeFirstResponder call, the search icon and placeholder text appear in the center of the textField.

[image]

Then, when the search bar becomes first responder, both animate to be left-aligned.

[image]

Because I'm doing both actions successively, I'm getting a weird animation where the icon & placeholder animate from (0,0).

How can I disable this animation, so that I can simply add the second image to my view?

**EDIT:**

I got the placeholder text to display correctly by using

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Type Here to Search"];
}
```

I can move the search icon using `[searchBar setPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(x, y) forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch];`, but the changes are still applied within the animation.

Answer (score 3):

@user3429963 is definitely [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22461081/1318939) in the right direction. Here's what worked for me:

```
searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
searchBar.removeLayerAnimationsRecursively()
```

where `removeLayerAnimationsRecursively()` is a function which removes animations from the view layer and its subviews' layers recursively:

```
extension UIView {

  func removeLayerAnimationsRecursively() {
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
    subviews.forEach { $0.removeLayerAnimationsRecursively() }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack but if you can't live without it.

EDIT: If you want the placeholder text too, you can do this.

set the placeholder text to @" " initially, and

```
[self.searchBar setText:@"Place holder"];

[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Place holder"];

[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

and after it becomes first Responder,

```
[self.searchBar setText:@""];
```

Comment: why are you setting the place holder text, use the text

Comment: I need the placeholder text so when the user starts typing, it goes away and is replaced with the typed character. For the search icon, I can animate it to a specified position using [setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon] but it still does so using an animation.

Comment: placeholder text will be center aligned. I don't think you can change that

Comment: No, the placeholder text is center aligned when the textField is inactive, then animates to left-aligned when it becomes firstResponder, then when the user presses a key, it disappears. It then reappears when the textField is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Certain number of spaces at the end of placeholder solved for me the issue. Note, it should be accurate number of spaces - not less and not more.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide icon of search bar  :-

```
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIcon.jpg"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Take transparent image with searchIcon.jpg name and your icon hide 
its work for me

```
[searchBar setText:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.searchController?.isActive = true
    self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it works for me (testing only on ios7)

```
@interface SearchBar : UISearchBar
@end

@implementation SearchBar
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self firstSubviewOfClass:[UITextField class]];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[textField firstSubviewMatchingBlock:^BOOL(UIView *obj) {
        return [obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && obj.layer.animationKeys.count;
    }];
    [imageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self firstSubviewOfClass:[UILabel class]];
    [label.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
@end
```